# How to participate in a Twitter "conversation"?

Tags: twitter

Let's say I see a Twitter conversation between other people, such as [this one](https://twitter.com/eevblog/status/608976365543497729), and obviously I have something witty and/or charming that I want to share with both the OP as well as anyone that may view the conversation in the future. How do I go about having my message added to the bottom of the conversation instead of replying to the OP privately or performing any of the half-dozen wrong things to do?

Answer (score 1):

You have couple of options:

- Prefix a `.`(or anything as a first character, as workaround of twitter's feature of message starting with `@` being shown only to your followers who follow the OP) before the OP's twitter handle so that it becomes a public tweet *and* notifying the OP about your message
- With the quote tweet feature, you can now click on the Retweet button and leave a comment which will be shown besides the OP's tweet